# I want to change the widget color dynamically when data will come server but i don't understand

Tags: sql-server, flutter, dart, socket.io, flutter-layout

I don't understand how to change dynamically widget color constantly based on the real-time data from the socket.io. **I want to change the widget color when data will come from the database.**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder<Room>(
  future: roomService.getRoom(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.data.length,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 5),
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          var values = snapshot.data!.data[index];
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(context, CupertinoModalPopupRoute(builder: (context)=>RoomDetailScreen(20, 30, 20+30)));
            },
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.r),
              ),
              color: Colors.green, //have to change here
              elevation: 6,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child:Text(
                  "${values['RType']}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 16.sp,
                      color: AppColors.whiteSec),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }else if(snapshot.hasError){
      return Center(
        child: Column(
          children: const [
            Center(child: Icon(Icons.error,color: AppColors.yellowPri,)),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to switch between 2 colours depending on the data.

```dart
 child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.r),
              ),
              color: snapshot.data == 'Room-1' ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,
              elevation: 6,
```

assuming that one of your data values is 'Room-1'.

If you'll be switching among multiple colours...

```dart
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    Map<String, Colour> colours = {
        'Room-1': Colours.green,
        'Room-2': Colours.blue,
        'Room-3': Colours.red,
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.data.length,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 5),
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          var values = snapshot.data!.data[index];
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(context, CupertinoModalPopupRoute(builder: (context)=>RoomDetailScreen(20, 30, 20+30)));
            },
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.r),
              ),
              color: Colors.green, //have to change here
              elevation: 6,
              child: Container(
    };
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      return GridView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.data.length,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 5),
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          var values = snapshot.data!.data[index];
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(context, CupertinoModalPopupRoute(builder: (context)=>RoomDetailScreen(20, 30, 20+30)));
            },
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.r),
              ),
              color: colours[snapshot.data],
              elevation: 6,
              child: Container(
```

> Note: Your question says that you want to change the colour 'when data will come from the database'. But since you are already using `snapshot.hasData`, the `GridView` itself won't be rendered without any data from the DB.

Comment: thanks @sidrao2006 . but the color change data will come from another api. I have to change the color by matching this room number with that room number and checking the status. example: if(snapshot.data!.data[index]['RNo']==upcomming room number && upcomming room status == 'R'){Colors.red}else if(snapshot.data!.data[index]['RNo']==upcomming room number && upcomming room status == 'C'){Colors.green}else{Colors.green}. I don't understand how to implement it. However the data will come from Socket IO. Color change will be realtime.